# Автоматическое уничтожение объекта

Tags: ооп, freepascal

1. Надо ли во Free Pascal заботится об уничтожении экземпляра объекта (использовать деструктор), если переменная, которая ссылалась на этот экземпляр, стала ссылаться на другой? Например:

   ```
   a:vector;

   a := vector.create(x1,y1);
   {вот "а" стало ссылаться на один объект класса vector}

   a := vector.create(x2,y2);
   {а теперь "а" стало ссылаться на другой объект класса vector}
   ```

   Удалится ли первый объект класса из памяти? Если нет, то как сделать чтобы да?
2. Где можно почитать подробно про ООП в Delphi/FreePascal? Именно про инструменты ООП в этих средах.
3. Правильно я понимаю, что если я перегрузил оператор:

   ```
   operator *(a:vector;b:single)c:vector;
   begin
       c:=vector.create(a.x*b,a.y*b);
   end;
   ```

   а потом, например, использовал этот оператор так:

   ```
   a1:=a1*b1 {a1,b1 и c1 типа vector }
   ```

   то то это неправильно, надо использовать его так:

   ```
   с1 := a1;
   a1 := c1 * b1;
   c1.free;
   ```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы понимаете под выражением "инструменты ооп". Вот вроде не плохая статья:

[http://codingrus.ru/readarticle.php?article_id=1932][1]


  [1]: http://codingrus.ru/readarticle.php?article_id=1932

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае первый объект никуда не денется, но для использования уже будет недоступен. Переменная `a` это, по сути, указатель на участок памяти где располагается объект созданный конструктором `Create`. То-есть, в начале у вас создается первый объект и его адрес заносится в переменную, а, потом, второй, и его адрес перезаписывает адрес первого.

[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov), написал как правильно уничтожать отработанные объекты. От себя хочу добавить что, если в коде работы с объектом могут сработать исключения, то его нужно экранировать конструкцией `try/finally/end`. Это даст возможность гарантированно уничтожить объект.

```
a := vector.create(x1,y1);
try
  // Здесь работаем с объектом "a"
finally
  a.Free;
end;
```

Также, для уничтожения объектов есть процедура `FreeAndNil()`. Она кроме уничтожения объекта еще и обнуляет переменную. Это удобно если в коде есть проверки через `Assigned()` создан объект или нет.

Comment: От себя хочу добавить, что try/finally/end лучше использовать даже в тех случаях, когда исключений не ожидается.

Answer (score 2):

[`TObject`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/tobject.html) - базовый класс для всех классов. Если ваш `vector` наследован от него или его потомков (если он объявлен как класс, то уже будет потомком `TObject`), то у него есть деструктор `Destroy`, который принято вызывать не напрямую, а через метод [`Free`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/tobject.free.html). Т.е.

```
MyObj := TMyObject.Create;

{какие-либо действия над объектом}

MyObj.Free;
MyObj := TMyObject.Create;

{работаем с другим объектом}

MyObj.Free;
```

Но лучше для читаемости кода всё же использовать разные переменные.